# UITextField: force resignFirstResponder when tapped outside of it

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitabbaritem, resignfirstresponder

I have a static `UITableView` that contains a number of `UITextField`s. When the user taps outside of any of the text fields I'd like to I'd like to dismiss the keyboard.

At the top level of my `UIViewController` is a `UITableView` and a `UITabBarItem`. I believe I'll also have to handle taps on the status bar.

I am unsure as how I should register for touches on them (so that I can force any of the text fields to call `resignFirstResponder`.

I thought I might have to handle `UIResponder`'s

`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

for the table view and tab bar item but neither of them are `UIControl`s so I can't use

`- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`

`UIWindow` is also a `UIResponder` but again, I can't seem to get touch events for it.

Any help would be much appreciated,
CS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a static `UITableView` it "eats" the touch events. So what I did was by subclassing `UITableView` and then added a delegate which reports touch events.

Answer (score 0):

If you had one text field I'd add touches began into the UIViewController it belongs to and do it like this...

```
- (void)touchesBegan ... cant remember full name
{
    if ([touches count] > 1) {
        return;
    }

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView self.view];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.textField.frame, touchPoint)) {
        //touch originated outside textField.

        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

If you have more than one text field then just do the CGRectContainsPoint check for each of them inside the if.

Comment: Fogmeister, thanks for your answer. I already have the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in my `UIViewController` subclass and it is not being called no matter where I tap. (I have an `NSLog()` in there and have a breakpoint set on it.